# Jquery Ajax Json Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Basically I am trying to return a list of names gotten from an Ajax request. When there is only one name, it works perfectly. However with multiple names I start seeing behavior I can't explain.

```
function getIDFromInput(input){
    sendToID = new Array; //An Array of "Name :Id" 
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "user_search.php",
        contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
        dataType:"json",
        async:false,    
        data: "q="+input,
        success:function(data){
            if(data.success){
                var userLength = data.success.length;                   
                if(userLength == 1){ // For one user everything works fine
                    var userNum = data.success.users[0];                        
                    var userName = data.success.usersNames[userNum];                        
                    sendToID[0] = userName + " :"+userNum;

                }
                else if(userLength > 1){ // Multiple users it fails

                    for(i = 0; i < userLength; i++){

                        var userNum = data.success.users[i];
                        //this call works
                        var userName = data.success.usersNames[userNum];
                        //this call fails, even though it seems to be the same call as above
                        sendToID[i] = userName + " :"+userNum;
                    }                       
                }
                else if(userLength < 1){ // never enter here
                }
            }           
        },
        error:function(data){ //After it fails it goes into here

        }
    });
    return sendToID;
}
```

The JSON I am passing back for < 2, ( The one that doesn't work, is below)

```
{"success":{"length":2,"userNames":[{"5":"Travis Baseler"},{"6":"Ravi Bhalla"}],"users":["5","6"]}}
```

The JSON I am passing back the one that does work is

```
{"success":{"length":"1","usersNames":{"6":"Ravi Bhalla"},"users":["6"]}}
```

Does anyone know why the first works but the second doesn't?

Comment: You should be avoiding synchronous AJAX requests when possible

Comment: @meagar: I know I'm going out on a limb here, but I'm sure there is a reason for it being synchronous. If he didn't know anything about JS/jQuery he wouldn't even know the option exists.

Comment: Once you get the data format straightened out so it's the same for all cases, you don't need the if/else at all.  You can do all three branches from the for loop.  The for loop handles length of 0, length of 1 and length of > 1 all automatically.

Comment: @josh Yet, here he is using synchronous AJAX calls.

Comment: @josh.trow
Sorry for betraying the confidence you show in me, but there isn't any good reason. I am assuming getJSON is the better method? How would I access the user name in the current scheme?

Comment: @Shane Chin: AAAAAAAUGH you're killing me man :) It must have been a copy/paste job then...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in your first example, `"usernames"` is an array, and in the seconds one it's an object
(notice the `[]` in the first example which don't exist in the second one).
see @meagar's comment which explains this better than I did.

some further points:
1. you're using numbers as object property names; this (IMO) is not recommended since it's a bit confusing.
2. you can obtain the length of the array using the `.length` property of an array:
`var userNum = data.success.users.length`
3. wouldn't it make more sense to have your objects in the format of `{ 'userNum': X, 'username': Y }`? that way you can return just one array:
`success: [ {'userNum': 5, 'username': 'Travis Baseler'}, {'userNum': 6, 'username': 'Ravi Bhalla'}]`

Comment: What he means is, `usernames["6"]` will work when `userNames` is `{"6" : "Ravi..."}`. But when you return an array in the form `[{"5":...},{"6":...}]`, `usernames["6"]` is no longer defined. You should be outputting `userNames` in the form `{"5":"Travis...", "6":"Ravi..."}`.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the input!!! With my current scheme, what would be the correct way to access the user's name?

For accessing an object wouldn't I use the "."? 

I will be changing my output method since above is much, much cleaner, but at this point I'm confused as to what is the correct syntax for above.
data.success.usersNames.userNum still fails.

Comment: with the current datatype, I think @scrappedcola has the right answer. but your main issues here are that: a. you're returning a different data structure for different cases, which is very bad (see @meagar's comment above), and b. you're returning data in a less than efficient way. If you try my suggestion, you can just do `success[i].userNum` or `success[i].username` which is much cleaner

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop should look like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < userLength; i++){
 var userNum = data.success.users[i];
   //this call works
  var userName = data.success.userNames[i][userNum];//you need to index the user in the array in the object uisng the loop then user the userNum to get your userName.
  sendToID[i] = userName + " :"+userNum;
 }
```